# What is a better approach to handle routing in a React button component?

Tags: reactjs, components

I want my button component to redirect the user on button click. Sometimes the button click will redirect the user to an external link. What is the best approach to do that?

I have a button component that handles routing and other onClick events. I was wondering what is a better approach to handle routing. I mean should i do like the code below?

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Button from "../Button/Button";
import Container from "../Container/Container";
import Header from "../Header/Header";
import "./Hero.css";

const Hero: React.FC = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClick = () => {
    navigate("/auth");
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <Container>
        <div className="hero">
          <div className="hero-content">
            <Header
              primaryHeader="An example app built using React.js 18, typescript."
              taglineHeader="I'm building a web app with React.js 18 and typescript. Aim of the project is to learn typescript."
            />
            <div className="action-buttons">
              <Button secondary label="get started" action={handleClick} />
              <Button label="github" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```

or should i wrap the button with a Link like below code ?

```
import Button from "../Button/Button";
import Container from "../Container/Container";
import Header from "../Header/Header";
import "./Hero.css";

const Hero: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <section>
      <Container>
        <div className="hero">
          <div className="hero-content">
            <Header
              primaryHeader="An example app built using React.js 18, typescript."
              taglineHeader="I'm building a web app with React.js 18 and typescript. Aim of the project is to learn typescript."
            />
            <div className="action-buttons">
<Link to='/'
              <Button secondary label="get started" />
</Link>
              <Button label="github" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```

I was thinking of another approach where i wrap the button component in a  tag then pass the path as a prop. like below.

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Button.css";

interface ButtonProps {
  label: string;
  secondary?: boolean;
  action?: () => void;
  path?: string;
}

const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({ label, secondary, action, path }) => {
  return (
    <Link to={path || ""}>
      <button
        className={secondary ? "button secondary" : "button"}
        onClick={action}
      >
        {label}
      </button>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

Or is there any other better approach. Also I may also redirect the user to a external link on button click sometimes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this too much job for the single reusable button component? Handling in app routing, navigating to the external links, plus handling any other kind of actions which your app intends to do. For this case I would add the callback function, which will be triggered on click event. For example:

```
export const Hero = (callback) => {
  return (
    <section>
      <Container>
        <div className="hero">
          <div className="hero-content">
            <Header
              primaryHeader="An example app built using React.js 18, typescript."
              taglineHeader="I'm building a web app with React.js 18 and typescript. Aim of the project is to learn typescript."
            />
            <div className="action-buttons">
              <Button secondary label="get started" action={callback} />
              <Button label="github" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </section>
  );
};
```

And now at the place where you use it:

```
<Hero callback={() => {do someting}}
```

I mean you can add all that functions to your reusable button component, but over time when your project grows, it will be hard to handle all that. You can add more "flag" props with which you will determine are you handling navigation to the external source, in app navigation or something else.

```
export const Hero = (callback, isExternalNav, isInAppNav) => {{/*rest of the logic*/}}
```

I hope this can help you a little.